# How to use main array in method?

Tags: java

I want to take user input for merge sorting so i'm using the array `ar[]` in the method but it gives error "cannot find symbol " for `ar[]`..

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
class Test
{
int Merge()
    {
    int q,p,r,i,l,m,j,t,k,w,x,s,u;
    w=q-p+1;
    x=r-q;
    int[] L=new int [w+1];
    int b=1;
    for(s=1;s<=w+1;s++)
        {
        L[b]=s;
        b++;
        }
    int[] R=new int [x+1];
    int c=1;
    for(t=1;u<=x+1;u++)
        {
        R[c]=u;
        c++;
        }
    for(i=1;i<=w;i++)
        {
        L[i]=ar[p+i-1];
        }
    for(j=1;j<=x;j++)
        {
        R[j]=ar[q+j];
        }
    L[w+1]=1000;
    R[x+1]=1001;
    i=1;
    j=1;
    for(k=p;k<=r;k++)
        {
        if(L[i]<=R[j])
            {
            ar[k]=L[i];
            i=i+1;
            }
        else 
            {
            ar[k]=R[j];
            j=j+1;
            }
        }
    System.out.println("sorted array"+ar[k]);
    }

public static void main(String ar[])
    {
    int a0=Integer.parseInt (ar[0]);
    int a1=Integer.parseInt (ar[1]);
    int a2=Integer.parseInt (ar[2]);
    int a3=Integer.parseInt (ar[3]);
    int a4=Integer.parseInt (ar[4]);
    int a5=Integer.parseInt (ar[5]);
    int a6=Integer.parseInt (ar[6]);
    int a7=Integer.parseInt (ar[7]);
    int a8=Integer.parseInt (ar[8]);
    int a9=Integer.parseInt (ar[9]);
    int p=a0,r=a9,q;

    if(p<r)
       q=(p+r)/2;

    Test T=new Test();
    T.Merge();
    }
}
```

Comment: *Please*, don't use single-letter variable names. It makes your code a lot easier to understand if you can tell what a variable does by looking at its name.

Answer (score 1):

`ar` is visible only in the scope of `main` method, it's unknown in other methods. In order to see it in other methods, you need to have a [class member](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html) that will hold its value.

Answer (score 1):

You have an `ar` local variable in the `main` method, but you don't have it in the `Merge` method. Local variables, and method parameter is just another kind of local variable, are... well, *local* to the method where they are declared. That means that such a variable is undefined in another method.

For example, you can have

```
 class Test {
   final int[] ar;
   Test(int[] ar) { this.ar = ar; }

   public static void main(String[] ar) {
      ....
      final Test t = new Test(ar);
      t.Merge();
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

ar is will be visible in main method only, you need to create a new array in main method. Copy values read into new array and pass this array as input to merge method.